# Measurement of Water Clarity

Tags: precipitation, environmental-chemistry

Turbidity is essentially the clarity of water. Turbidity can be measured in many ways such as a turbidimeter, secci disk or a turbidity tube (which incorporates a secci disk at the bottom). If you had a small turbid water sample - 20mL, how could you measure the turbidity without an electronic device??

Comment: There's a lot of portable turbidity meters with different light sources available. Your choice depends on the the standards that you have to follow: EPA = tungsten filament, ISO = IR leds.

Comment: I'm not sure how thats relating to my question?

Comment: Let me reiterate the question: Measuring the turbidity of a small sample size (20mL) in the cheapest way.

Comment: First of all, please make your question clear. You ***changed*** your question here in the comments.

Comment: wow, i think a mod changed it sorry

Answer (score 1):

Turbidity is measured by the examining the light passing through a sample.  A sample's turbidity is formally measured using standardized methods (e.g. ISO 7027 or "Standard Methods," No. 2130B. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbidity)).  Standardized methods require the instrumentation called for by the standard.

An informal measure of visible differences in turbidity can be obtained by comparing the 20mL sample to a set of calibrated standards.  An example of a set of calibration standards for turbidity are shown in the following link http://www.water.ncsu.edu/watershedss/info/turbid.html.